# How to read current docker tag inside dockerfile?

Tags: docker

How to read current docker tag inside dockerfile?

```
Example:
// run in cmd
docker build . -t thisismytag

// docker file
FROM node:14-alpine AS build

RUN echo $TAG // prints thisismytag
```

Comment: why do you need tag in dockerfile? it makes no sense since you can tag a docker image after building using `docker tag` command.

Comment: Beucase I would like to write it into config file during the build of my nodejs app. And then I would like to show it in my nodejs app - when container runing. Just for "debug info".

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in the tag as a separate argument

```
docker build -t thisismytag --build-arg TAG=thisismytag
```

and in the dockerfile

```
FROM node:14-alpine AS build
ARG TAG=unknown
RUN echo $TAG // prints thisismytag
```

But, as already stated in a comment, the image tag may change after the image was built. This would not be reflected in the image.